# Open recently closed file in Notepad++ using keyboard shortcut

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

Is it possible to reopen mistakenly closed file in Notepad++ using keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl + Shift + T`). Most web browsers have this feature, if you close a tab by mistake.

Can we do that in NPP too?

Answer (score 9):

As a matter of fact,  `Ctrl+Shift+t` reopen last closed file in Notepad++ (version 7.6). But the file must be named (this shortcut do not work on `new 1` and similar files).

Comment: Thanks. I am stuck at the older version of Notepad++, due to some admin restrictions. Is this functionality possible in the older versions ( I am still at v6.5)

Comment: @Cricrazy, unfortunately I can't get older version. But you can try to map a key (if you see it as function). Or maybe try new version with portable apps (do not need install)

Comment: I don't have a copy of NPP that old right now.  To determine for yourself whether the functionality is there, look at **File** menu, and see if the entry **Restore Recent Closed File** is there; if that's lacking, maybe **Open All Recent Files**.  If it is there, but doesn't have a keyboard shortcut, you can use **Settings > Shortcut Mapper**, as @Romeo-Ninov suggested.

Comment: @Cricrazy use the PortableApp version instead.  That's recent enough to have this shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have it setup already, you can have notepad++ "save" files automatically into notepad++ in case notepad++ gets closed or computer shuts down.

You will go to Settings -> Preferences -> Backup -> Enable session snapshot and periodic backup

At this point you will be able to close notepad++ and if you open it back up your files that you had open will still be there. You can also shutdown your computer and open notepad++ backup and your files that you had open will be there.

Also like what Romeo mentioned, you can press control + shift + t, and it will open your last txt document, but it will not work for unsaved txt documents.

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

After my comment earlier today, I found a bit of time and downloaded a portable v6.5 (from Sept 2013).  It has that functionality, kind of, though under different names.

Once you close one or more tabs, the **File** menu will have a list of most-recently-closed files.  You can click on the appropriate number, and it will re-open that file.  So the keyboard sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> (a sequence, not holding them down) will open the most-recently-closed.  It's not quite as simple as <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd>, but it's the same number of finger-presses.  And just below that, **Open All Recent Files** will open all the recently-closed files.  Unfortunately, neither of those has entries in the **Shortcut Mapper...** for v6.5.

I tried some experiments: I looked up the MessageID's from 7.6.2, which are **Open All Recent Files** (MessageID=42040) and **Restore Recent Closed File** (41021), and compared those to the codes in the 6.5 source code: I found **Open All Recent Files** was still 42040, but couldn't find an equivalent of **Restore Recent Closed File**.  I tried adding a shortcut for both of those, or for just the 42040, by editing `shortcuts.xml` in the `<InternalCommands>` section, and exiting/reloading.... But NPPv6.5 didn't do anything when I tried those shortcuts, and when I exited and reloaded again, those shortcuts disappeared from `shortcuts.xml`: so NPPv6.5 doesn't want shortcuts for even that known ID=42040.

So, the best I have to offer is to ask your Admin to install a newer version.  As the best workaround I can find, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> in sequence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great finding. Thank you. In fact, I can also use `ALT` + `Down Arrow` + Number.  This also seems to be an option, `ALT` (with a fraction of sec pause) enables first menu, which is `File` menu, and then I can pick any number to reopen that file. 

So, if I closed a file by mistake, I can simply do `ALT` + `DownArrow` + `1`. A good work around. Appreciate your investigation.